# jQuery Masonry not aligning or filling images in the grid properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to set up a masonry layout for a portfolio website but the images don't seem to align in the grid properly as items tend to overlap each other. Can someone point out if I'm utilizing the jQuery correctly or if it's a different issue I'm running into? Thanks!

I made sure I'm calling the right selectors, the items seem to keep overlapping.

**jQuery**

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
}

img {
  max-width:200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

**Here's how I linked the .js, which are both in my project folder**

```html
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type:"text/css">
  <title>Victor Zhang</title>

  <script src="./masonry.pkgd.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="./masonryjQuery.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**Rest of my HTML**

```
  <div class="grid">

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/Venmo-Final.gif">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/EQT.png">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/ezgif-4-99d82a0722.gif">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/Homepage+1+-+Standard+Web.png">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/steam+app+gif.gif">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/Bounce-Morph---Final-Cut_2.gif">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/BART+Map+Final-02.png">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/arkangel2.png">
      </div>

      <div class="grid-item">
          <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/CIG.png">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I figured that should be enough for the masonry grid to work but my images are overlapping and not filling in the spaces correctly. Do I need to define more explicit parameters in my CSS? Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: When I try this it looks pretty good at several widths. I don't think I see overlap (although the img srcs are a bit busy) I'm not clear on what you're expecting to see that's different.  Can you refer to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tdreid/a0bey5mp/) and describe the difference more clearly―or post your own public playground example?

Comment: Hi Trevor,

I've attached an image of what I see in the jsfiddle you added here: https://imgur.com/a/tzvrxEO.

Basically, it looks like 'Steam App' gif is on top of the 'My App' gif which is on top of the 'Venmo' gif and I want the page to show the entire gif and just have the next gif or image follow right under it instead of them laying on top of one another. 

Here's an example of how the 'My App' gif should look: https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/victorzhangportfolio/ezgif-4-99d82a0722.gif

I hope that makes sense, let me know if I can clarify my explanation a little more :).

Answer (score 0):

By any chance if you have a luxury of choosing pure CSS implementation of masonry layout over the jQuery plugin, check [this](https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) out. See the way [CSS column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns) property is used there.

Meanwhile, if the jQuery plugin you're using is also internally following the same approach, I suspect 'float' might be the culprit!

Comment: Hi Sujit,

Thanks for the links! I'll check it out and see if I can implement the layout this way. I'll let you know how that goes!